# Alternative to union and where statement to bucket age and group by a column SQL Impala

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, impala, bucket

Given a table like:

```
+----+-----------+------------------+
| id | code      | age              |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | 315.32000 | 2.18430371791803 |
| 1  | 315.32000 | 3.18430371791803 |
| 1  | 800.00000 | 2.18430371791803 |
| 2  | 315.32000 | 5.64822705794013 |
| 3  | 800.00000 | 5.68655778752176 |
| 3  | 120.12000 | 5.70572315231258 |
| 4  | 315.32000 | 5.72488851710339 |
| 4  | 315.32000 | 5.74405388189421 |
| 5  | 120.12000 | 5.7604813374292  |
| 6  | 315.32000 | 5.77993740687426 |
| .. | ...       | ...              |
+----+-----------+------------------+
```

I'm using:

```
SELECT code, COUNT(*) AS code_frequency,'0-10' AS age_range
FROM table 
WHERE age >= 0 AND age < 10
GROUP BY code 
ORDER BY code_frequency DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT code, COUNT(*) AS code_frequency,'10-20' AS age_range
FROM table
WHERE age >= 10 AND age < 20
GROUP BY code 
ORDER BY code_frequency DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
...
ORDER BY age_range
```

And I am repeating this with slightly different age ranges and logic multiple times to output a table that shows the most frequent code with the highest frequency, along with it's frequency, for each age group.

output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| code      | frequency | age_range |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 315.32000 | 99832     | 0-10      |
| 800.00000 | 45223     | 10-20     |
| ...       | ...       | ...       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same output, without repeating the same code blocks and using union?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a `case` expression to define the group:

```
select
    code,
    count(*) frequency,
    case 
        when age >= 0  and age < 10 then '0-10'
        when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-20'
    end age_range
from mytable
group by code, age_range
order by age_range
```

If you want the most frequent code per age group, then you can use `row_number()` on top of the query:

```
select code, frequence, age_range
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by age_range order by frequency desc) rn
    from (
        select
            code,
            count(*) frequency,
            case 
                when age >= 0  and age < 10 then '0-10'
                when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-20'
            end age_range
        from mytable
        group by code, age_range
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Or better yet:

```
select code, frequence, age_range
from (
    select
        code,
        count(*) frequency,
        case 
            when age >= 0  and age < 10 then '0-10'
            when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-20'
        end age_range,
        row_number() over(partition by min(age) order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable
    group by code, age_range
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: The first code block you provide does work (so impala does support aliasing in the group by clause), but your code isn't providing the same output. I only need the single most frequent code and it's frequency, for each age group. Is there a way of ordering by frequency desc and limiting to 1 for each case? I'm trying to add this in and am getting errors no matter where I try to throw it in.

Comment: @GMB . . . You have an extra subquery that is not needed.  Aggregation functions and window functions can be combined in the same expression.  In this case, you can use (`partition by min(age) order by count(*) desc`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thank you (I was thinking on how to avoid this additional level).